# Khovanov homology definition using vector spaces, Z-modules, abelian groups?

Tags: khovanov-homology

When I read various papers on Khovanov homology, sometimes it is defined in terms of graded vector spaces, sometimes as graded $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. Is there a difference? E.g. can the vector field definition find torsion in the homology or does it just return the free part?
Why isn't the Khovanov constructed using Abelian groups, wouldn't this be the simplest?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a difference- Khovanov homology over $\mathbb{Z}$ often has torsion elements of different orders which cannot all be visible over $\mathbb{F}_{p^k}$ for any $p$. See Shumakovitch https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0405474.pdf for a survey. There is also an "odd" variant of Khovanov homology (https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.4300) that agrees with the standard Khovanov homology over $\mathbb{F}_2$ but disagrees over $\mathbb{Z}$.